# Do I need GPU to run LLama2 example python codes after I download the model from meta?

Tags: llama

I downloade the LLama2 model from meta, and I can't run it having the impression that I need GPU.
I don't have GPU currently and the example is not working.
Bard insist to me that I don't need GPU, also I read that I can download a .cpp app that uses LLama2 without GPU, but the code that Meta is giving in their example I thing requires GPU.
Is this true?

I tried to run the examples that comes with the model in pyton, using python3, without success.
I am not sure why the example did not run. I have the impression is my lack of GPU

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with a library version.

I follow step by step for this video.
It can run with CPU only.
but you have to check a version of library(requirements.txt) before install/or import  library.

[Follow this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N7wk1E1I0Qo)